# mongodb dies on regex search

Tags: regex, mongodb

Simple regex search:

```
> db.lipsum.find({"d.text":{$regex:'cursus'}});
```

does well, and returns many thousands.

A bit more complex one:

```
db.lipsum.find({"d.text":{$regex:'cursus((?!turpis massa).)*$'}});
```

kills the mongod:

```
Tue Nov 26 11:01:03 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Tue Nov 26 11:01:03 query failed : lipsum.lipsum { d.text: { $regex: "cursus((?!turpis massa).)*$" } } to: 127.0.0.1:27017
Error: error doing query: failed
Tue Nov 26 11:01:03 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Nov 26 11:01:03 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
```

There is nothing in mongodb.log. The last lines are:

```
Tue Nov 26 11:00:17 [conn2] query lipsum.lipsum query: { d.text: { $regex: "cursus" } } cursorid:5200338523215960499 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:1266 nreturned:101 reslen:159838 1ms
Tue Nov 26 11:00:18 [conn2] run command admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1.0, forShell: 1.0 }
Tue Nov 26 11:00:18 [conn2] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetGetStatus: 1.0, forShell: 1.0 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:76 0ms
```

So there are 2 questions:

1. How to get detailed information what happened ?
2. How to write correct regex to fetch objects that have no "turpis massa" after "cursus"?

---

Mongodb 2.2.4, Ubuntu 13.04.

My testing db:

```
load("lorem.js"); // from https://github.com/f/loremjs

var lorem = new Lorem;
lorem.type = Lorem.TEXT;
lorem.query = '2p';

for(var i=0; i < 20000; i++){
    db.lipsum.insert({t: $currentDate, d: {text:lorem.createLorem()}})
}
```

Comment: Could you try the same query with the current version of MongoDb?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yes, it works with 2.4.5 and 2.4.8 on a vagrant box.

Comment: Seems like a a bug was fixed between versions.

Comment: Agree, and appreciate @WiredPrairie for pointing it. I am still interesting how to collect debug information to understand what happened. For self-educational purposes, if you will.